# Android - cannot set variable in databinding (via ViewDataBinding), what to do?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have a layout file for my MainActivity, with this as the data tag:

```
<data>
  <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.me.app.MainViewModel" />
  <variable name="main_activity" type="com.me.app.MainActivity" />
</data>
```

In my MainActivity, I set these variables like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private var mainViewModel : MainViewModel? = null

  override fun onCreate() {
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    val binding : ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.setVariable(BR.main_activity, this)
    binding.setVariable(BR.viewmodel, mainViewModel)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
  }
}
```

After this code segment, the `main_activity` variable is correctly set, but the `viewmodel` variable seems to remain an instance of MainViewModel that holds all the default values even after setting them later on `mainViewModel` (I use MutableLiveData objects in the ViewModel, and set their contents using .value). Why is it that one is set, and the other is not?

Comment: Show us your ViewModel content and your XML usage of these MutableLiveData

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira Found out what was the problem - see answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer - **I forgot to remove the "usual" setContentView from onCreate()**. The code posted in the question doesn't have that.